# $A, B\subseteq X$. Then, $A^{\perp}=(\overline{A})^{\perp}=(span A)^{\perp}=(span \overline{A})^{\perp}=\left(\overline{span A}\right)^{\perp}$

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

We know that $A\subseteq B\Rightarrow B^{\perp}\subseteq A^{\perp}$ (This is immediate). For this $A^{\perp}\supseteq(\overline{A})^{\perp}$ and $(span A)^{\perp}\supseteq(span \overline{A})^{\perp}$, because $A\subseteq \overline{A}$. I imagine it is possible to show that

\begin{equation}\tag{H}
A^{\perp}\supseteq(\overline{A})^{\perp}\supseteq(span A)^{\perp}\supseteq(span \overline{A})^{\perp}\supseteq\left(\overline{span A}\right)^{\perp}.
\end{equation}

But i dont know how to show $(span \overline{A})^{\perp}\supseteq\left(\overline{span A}\right)^{\perp}$ and $(\overline{A})^{\perp}\supseteq(span A)^{\perp}$. If we can showing (H), we had using: [If $x\perp E$ then $x\perp\overline{\text{span}E}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083509/if-x-perp-e-then-x-perp-overline-textspane) for conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{span} \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{\operatorname{span}A}$. Then use the lemma:

**Lemma:** $A \subseteq B\implies B^\perp \subseteq A^\perp$.

Conclude that $(\overline{\operatorname{span}A})^\perp \subseteq (\operatorname{span} \overline{A})^\perp.$

I will now show $\operatorname{span}(A)^\perp\subseteq \overline{A}^\perp.$

Indeed, if $x \in \operatorname{span}(A)^\perp$, we obviously have $x \perp A$ and then by continuity of the inner product also $x \perp \overline{A}$ [if $y \in \overline{A}$, choose a sequence $(a_n)_n$ in $A$ with $y= \lim_n a_n$ and note that $\langle x,y\rangle = \lim_n \langle x,a_n\rangle = 0$] so  $x \in \overline{A}^\perp.$

Comment: you are my hero!